# About one to one

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Let $y=f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ on $x>0$. Show that $f$ is one to one on $[1, 2]$.

Can anybody help in this case?

There is also one more question: evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1-\cos{6x})^2}{x^4}$. I found there is no limit is that true?

Sorry I could write this more carefully but exam will start in 2 hours.

Why do you people down vote by the way?

Comment: Hope, my answer could help you ...

Comment: Reasons for the downvotes (not mine). You should show some work on the question - what did you try? Where are you confused?  Just one question per post, please,  so your "also" should be another question. Try not to ask just two hours before your exam - there are better ways to study, and to use this site to your advantage. When you get a good answer you should accept it (the check mark) and upvote it (the up arrow). You can upvote more than one answer. Finally, welcome to Math SE.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}\ge 0$$ for $x\ge 1$ with equality only for $x=1$. Hence, $f$ is strictly increasing on $[1,2]$.

The taylor-expansion of $\ (1-\cos(6x))^2\ $ is $\ 324x^4+O(x^6)\ $, so the limit is $324$.

Answer (score 2):

if $x,y \ge 1$ and $x+\frac{1}{x}=y+\frac{1}{y}$ then show that

$$yx(x-y)=x-y.$$

This gives $x=y$ or $xy=1$. Since $x,y \ge 1$ it follows that $x=y$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! And I'd be happy if you answer my second question too. No need if that is true

Answer (score 1):

The first question has been sufficiently addressed.  Here's another way to do the second one, without Taylor series.

\begin{align*}
  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1-\cos 6x)^2}{x^4} &= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{(1-\cos 6x)(1-\cos 6x)}{x^2 \cdot x^2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos 6x}{x^2} \cdot \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos 6x}{x^2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \left(\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos 6x}{x^2}\right)^2
\end{align*}
I should point out that the second-to-last equality above (where I split the limit of a product into the product of limits) only works if both limits in the second-to-last line above exist.  In light of the last line above, we really only need to consider $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos6x}{x^2}$.  So let's do that, using l'Hopital's rule twice.  (We could've tried that from the start, but I don't want to repeatedly differentiate $(1- \cos6x)^2$).
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos 6x}{x^2} &= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{6\sin 6x}{2x}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{36\cos 6x}{2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= 18
\end{align*}
So we have
$$
  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1-\cos 6x)^2}{x^4} = \cdots
    = \left(\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos 6x}{x^2}\right)^2
    = (18)^2
    = 324.
$$